# ctc blstm with keras error during training

Tags: keras

I'm trying to train a blstm with ctc loss for speech sequence recognition. I managed to get the code running but the training fails at a specific step of the second epoch with the following error:

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:993] Invalid argument: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
     [[Node: ctc/scan/strided_slice = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](ctc/scan/Shape, ctc/scan/strided_slice/stack, ctc/scan/strided_slice/stack_1, ctc/scan/strided_slice/stack_2)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "speech_lstm_ctc.py", line 212, in <module>
    callbacks=[earlystopping, checkpoint, data_gen])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 88, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1876, in fit_generator
    class_weight=class_weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1620, in train_on_batch
    outputs = self.train_function(ins)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 2073, in __call__
    feed_dict=feed_dict)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 767, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 965, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1015, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1035, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
     [[Node: ctc/scan/strided_slice = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](ctc/scan/Shape, ctc/scan/strided_slice/stack, ctc/scan/strided_slice/stack_1, ctc/scan/strided_slice/stack_2)]]
     [[Node: ctc/scan/while/Less_1/_77 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_981_ctc/scan/while/Less_1", tensor_type=DT_BOOL, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](^_cloopctc/scan/while/TensorArrayReadV3/_17)]]

Caused by op u'ctc/scan/strided_slice', defined at:
  File "speech_lstm_ctc.py", line 189, in <module>
    loss_out = Lambda(ctc_lambda_func, output_shape=(1,), name="ctc")([y_pred, labels, input_length, label_length])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 554, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/layers/core.py", line 659, in call
    return self.function(inputs, **arguments)
  File "speech_lstm_ctc.py", line 141, in ctc_lambda_func
    ctc_batch_loss = K.ctc_batch_cost(labels, y_pred, input_length, label_length)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 3258, in ctc_batch_cost
    sparse_labels = tf.to_int32(ctc_label_dense_to_sparse(y_true, label_length))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 3222, in ctc_label_dense_to_sparse
    initializer=init, parallel_iterations=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/functional_ops.py", line 524, in scan
    n = array_ops.shape(elems_flat[0])[0]
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 495, in _SliceHelper
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 653, in strided_slice
    shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 3688, in strided_slice
    shrink_axis_mask=shrink_axis_mask, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 763, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2327, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1226, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()

InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): slice index 0 of dimension 0 out of bounds.
     [[Node: ctc/scan/strided_slice = StridedSlice[Index=DT_INT32, T=DT_INT32, begin_mask=0, ellipsis_mask=0, end_mask=0, new_axis_mask=0, shrink_axis_mask=1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"](ctc/scan/Shape, ctc/scan/strided_slice/stack, ctc/scan/strided_slice/stack_1, ctc/scan/strided_slice/stack_2)]]
     [[Node: ctc/scan/while/Less_1/_77 = _Recv[client_terminated=false, recv_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0", send_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0", send_device_incarnation=1, tensor_name="edge_981_ctc/scan/while/Less_1", tensor_type=DT_BOOL, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](^_cloopctc/scan/while/TensorArrayReadV3/_17)]]
```

The function implementing the ctc loss is the following:

```
def ctc_lambda_func(args):
    y_pred, labels, input_length, label_length = args
    # the 2 is critical here since the first couple outputs of the RNN
    # tend to be garbage:
    y_pred = y_pred[:, 2:, :]

    ctc_batch_loss = K.ctc_batch_cost(labels, y_pred, input_length, label_length)

    return ctc_batch_loss
```

I believe that the error does not have to do with a specific input because it appears every time at the same step even with different inputs.

Any ideas on what might be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that what caused the problem was the batch generator actually gave a mini-batch of size 1 at some point and caused tensorflow to crash. Corrected it by making the mini-batches be larger than 1 at all times.